# How to optimize formatting of a series of unknown range values

Tags: math, formatting, format

hope this question is close enough to programming topics to be asked on stackoverflow.

I am looking for a way to format a series of values to be as short as possible but still respecting their distribution.

Short example:

Having a series of values like:

```
1000, 3500, 400
```

can be easily formatted as:

```
1k, 3.5k, 0.4k (by dividing them by 1000 of course)
```

But given that I don't know how high my single values will be what could be an approach to determine the right level of dividing?

I could look at the first value in my series and do a simple check whether it is able to be divided by 1000, 1000000 or something else but this could lead me into trouble, e.g. in this example:

```
1000000, 1000, 4000, 500
```

When I check for the first or the highest value in my row this could easily end up in a format like this:

```
1m, 0.001m, 0.004m, 0.0005m
```

while the 'best' format in this case propably would be

```
1000k, 1k, 4k, 0.5k
```

I know that there can't be a perfect solution when no kind of 'regular base' is existing within a series, but is there a way to determine the 'leading base' within a series?

Comment: Use the median of the values to decide on the format.

Comment: or format each value separately using the SI prefixes `T,G,M,k,m,u,n,p` which one to use can be easily decided by `log1000(value)`. Also I edited the question replacing figure with value as figure implies image (and formating images is entirely different matter)